# Read and update a Dictionary type PSMultiValueSpecifier from NSUserDefault

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uipickerview, nsuserdefaults

Does anyone know how to easily read a Dictionary type PSMultiValueSpecifier from NSUserDefault into a UIPickViewer control and save changes back to NSUserDefaults using iPhone SDK 3.0? If so, can you post some specific code to efficiently do this?

Answer (score 1):

The following code turns the PSMultiValueSpecifier Values and Titles into a nice dictionary which you can use with your UIPickViewer.

`NSString* settingsBundle = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"bundle"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Root.plist"];`

```
NSDictionary* rootPlist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:settingsBundle];

if (rootPlist == nil)
    return nil;

NSArray* specifiers = [rootPlist objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];

NSDictionary *multiValueSpecifier = nil;

for (NSDictionary *specifier in specifiers)
{
    if ([[specifier objectForKey:@"Key"] isEqualToString:speficierKey] == YES &&
        [[specifier objectForKey:@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"PSMultiValueSpecifier"] == YES)
    {
        multiValueSpecifier = specifier;
        break;
    }
}

if (multiValueSpecifier == nil)
    return nil;

NSArray* titlesArray = [multiValueSpecifier objectForKey:@"Titles"];
NSArray* valuesArray = [multiValueSpecifier objectForKey:@"Values"];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:titlesArray 
                                                       forKeys:valuesArray];

return dictionary;
```

To save it you need to save the KEY and not the value of the dictionary.

`[settings setObject:dictionaryKey forKey:@"mySelection_preference"];`